# Graduate Research Fellowships

Tags: application, funding

Recently, I have been looking around for suitable fellowships. I'm an american, white male, mechanical engineering major with a research focus on solid mechanics and fracture. I will graduate from undergraduate in December, and start my MS immediately. My long term goal is to find an academic position, after I finish my MS, PhD, and post-doc.

Other than the NSF GRFP, is anyone aware of fellowships I may be suitable for?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not so familiar with engineering - will you be starting a separate MS, or going straight into a MS/PhD program?  There is usually not much fellowship funding available for standalone masters students.

Comment: Separate MS, PhD at a different program.

Comment: So, you may not be eligible for those fellowships until you start your PhD program.  Anyhow, google for "engineering fellowships" gives many options - Hertz and NDSEG are famous ones.

Comment: I had previously seen NSDEG, which is supposed to be for students beginning PhD. Although, I can still *technically* apply.

Comment: Hertz actually appears to be a good idea, I will look closely at this application.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why did you feel the need to specify you are a 'white male' ? Note: I am not criticising or attacking you in any way. Just asking.

Comment: Because many fellowships are specifically tailored to students of underrepresented minorities, I wanted to be clear that I am not eligible for these fellowships.

Answer (score 1):

There's this fund:

http://www.scheppfoundation.org/wp/

As well as this fund, if your parents were immigrants to the U.S.:

https://www.pdsoros.org.

There are more, just Google search a bit.

As an aside, I believe this question falls under the category of "boat programming" and is thus not suitable for this site.

Comment: I think it counts as a shopping question rather than boat programming.